# Centering container for ipad

Tags: css, ipad

am trying to find a way of centering my div #container on the ipad page.
It's a fairly simple 960px wide, margin 0 auto job. The body is given a background color but on the ipad either the container just takes up the whole page or the margin works on the left but the page is stuck to the right hand edge.

I've seen various ideas posted over the internet about min-width, viewport etc.
Ideally I'd use @media queries in my stylesheet as everything else looks fine by default

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure < body > isn't overlapping iPad viewport?

Comment: Sorry Mat for not understanding but could you be more specific?

Comment: Is the width of the body <= 1024px?

Comment: The body has no width set. The container is set to 960px with 40px padding.

Answer (score 1):

In the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), total width of an element is the sum of its margin, borders, padding and content width.

Total width of your container is `40 + 960 + 40 = 1040px`, while iPad viewport width is 1024px. So you cannot center and you can see unexpected results!

Reduce width or padding of the container to make its total width less than 1024px, `width:960px; padding:32px;` eg.

Comment: Thanks, yep you're totally right I was just being stupid with my calculations - however I have found that even though reducing the size of the various div widths gets the container to fit nicely in the ipad, it doesn't leave it dead-centered? Is that an Ipad thing as far as you're aware or do you think there's some margin issue in my code? Thanks again

Comment: I don't know any issue about horizontally centering, so I think it's due to your code. Can I see it?

Comment: Even better, because mobile Safari on the iPad and iPhone supports the border-box property you can simple go; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; and it'll stop padding altering your widths.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `DIV`'s display attribute from the default block to `inline-block`.

```
div #container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```